# Clear and add new data in file - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, file

I have a csv file in my assets folder.

file path - 'assets/data.csv'

I am able to read the file like this

```
  readLocalCSVFile() {
    this._http.get('assets/data.csv', { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
  }
```

How can I delete the existing content in file and also write new content in the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, because the client side application cannot write to server side asset folder. You need to implement a server side part. i is up to you which technology to use.

If it is not important, that the file is written to the server and the only this you want to do is to update the data for the user you maybe interested in the "filesystem" api. But this is not fully implemented by all the browsers.

In this case you can write data to a sandbox. Information about the support: https://caniuse.com/?search=filesystem

...

Regarding you example: There is a function on the http client
`this._http.delete` but a i mentioned you need to implement the server side part.

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can't edit the files.
But, I think this might help you through this you can easily interact with the local files:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-in-memory-web-api